# Error: Cannot find module 'dateformat' in gulp

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, gulp

I'm working with nodejs (version v4.2.1)
I would like to work with gulp
I've installed gulp (3.9.0)
But when I try my default script with an empty function (script below) with the command
gulp
I get the error

> Error: Cannot find module 'dateformat'

I've tried to install dateformat with

```
npm install -g dateformat
```

I can check that dateformat is installed with the command
dateformat --help
But the gulp script produce the same error

> Error: Cannot find module 'dateformat'

I'm working with Windows 7

Any help?

==================== script

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
});
```

Comment: Try reinstalling gulp globally.

Answer (score 11):

Had a similar issue and reinstalling gulp globally indeed fixed the issue, **however**, see my details regarding prior installations of node (since you mention it as well)

```
npm uninstall gulp -g
npm install gulp -g
```

The explanation is difficult to precisely offer, since I embarked on an entire troubleshooting effort, but if it is of any help - I suspect the issue is a result of installing node, but the installer is not overwriting prior versions of npm - somehow causing an internal issue somewhere. Troubleshooting flow:

1. uninstall node
2. delete the `nodejs` folder, located by default at ~\Program Files\ *(orphaned node_modules with npm folder found here)*
3. reinstall node
4. globally uninstall/reinstall gulp

Some more details on the issue can be found here: [npm 3 broken when installed from official OS X Node.js installer #10434](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10434). While this is specific to OSX, I found the situation identical to myself on the Windows side.

Comment: Worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by

1. Delete *node_modules* folder
2. `npm install`

Comment: Great! It's very helpful!